# How to generate strings from a data frame of word frequencies

Tags: r, dataframe, word-frequency

Suppose that I have the following data frame containing word frequencies:

```
      Bob   Joe Go  Eat Run
doc1    2   0   0   1   2 
doc2    0   1   1   2   0
```

I need to generate a char vector such as follows:

```
chr[1:2] "Bob Bob Eat Run Run"
         "Joe Go Eat Eat"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
df <- data.frame(Bob = c(2, 0), Joe = c(0, 1), Go = c(0, 1), Eat = c(1, 2), Run = c(2, 0))
row.names(df) <- c('doc1', 'doc2')
df
     Bob Joe Go Eat Run
doc1   2   0  0   1   2
doc2   0   1  1   2   0

apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(rep(names(df), x), collapse = ' '))
                 doc1                  doc2 
"Bob Bob Eat Run Run"      "Joe Go Eat Eat"
```

If you don't like the 'named' vectors like above, and want a straight character vector, you can do this instead:

```
as.character(apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(rep(names(df), x), collapse = ' ')))
[1] "Bob Bob Eat Run Run" "Joe Go Eat Eat"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table', grouped by sequence of rows, `unlist` the columns, replicate the column names of df by it, 
and then `paste` it together.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, toString(rep(names(df), unlist(.SD))) ,1:nrow(df)]$V1
#[1] "Bob, Bob, Eat, Run, Run" "Joe, Go, Eat, Eat"
```

---

Or using `tapply` from `base R`

```
tapply(unlist(df), row(df), FUN= function(x) 
                     toString(rep(names(df), x)))
```